# Mocking repository method returns null instead expected value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
   ICarRepository CarRepository { get; }
   ...
}

ICarRepository has (besides other methods) GetById(int id) method. 
That call I want to mock inside IUnitOfWork mock.

[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
   
    unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.CarRepository.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new Car(){Name = "test"});
    
    var car = unitOfWork.Object.CarRepository.GetById(1); 
    //returns null

   var car2 = await unitOfWork.Object.CarRepository.GetById(1); 
    //returns null
        
    Any thoughts?
}
```

UPDATE:

```
public interface ICarRepository : IRepository<Car, int>
{
}

public interface IRepository<T, TId> where T : Entity<TId>
{
   Task<T?> GetById(TId id);
}
public class Car : Entity<int>
{   
}
```

I'm expecting that car should be populated with whatever I passed in Returns statement in the mock setup but instead I'm getting null.

Comment: Exactly :) typo. Changed, the issue remains though

Comment: It looks like the GetById function you are mocking is on IUnitOfWork instead of ICarRepository - are you sure the code is correct?

Comment: @cbp sorry for confusion, I update the code which represents now the situation i'm having. I'm mocking CarRepository.GetById. Issue remains

Comment: I don't think that mocks work this way. You need to mock the `carRepository`, inject it into `unitOfWork` and then test `unitOfWork`

Comment: EDITED: You use `.ReturnsAsync`, but Moq has this method only for the setup of a function that returns `Task<>`. So your example is not complete. Take more care to bring an example that actually reproduces your situation.

Comment: You're returning async, but not awaiting async on the get

Comment: @VladDX Moq normally supports "long" setups like this, `.Setup(x => x.CarRepository.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))` and the "intermediate" mock is created automatically.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, today I've learnt something 

Comment: @VladDX There is a vague indication you can do stuff like that on Moq's [Quickstart page](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) when they say `// auto-mocking hierarchies (a.k.a. recursive mocks)` `mock.Setup(foo => foo.Bar.Baz.Name).Returns("baz");` Written under Properties, but in my experience it works with methods as well. And I cannot see why it would not work when the last method is async/awaitable, so not sure if that is relevant for the asker's problem. Edit: The very last example on the page also uses recursive syntax with so-called LINQ to Mocks, including a method.

Comment: @user1765862, you configure an async mock but make a non-async call.

Comment: I tried with  await unitOfWork.Object.CarRepository.GetById(1); but I still getting null.

Comment: I have not reproduced locally (yet). Can you try to change to `var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>(MockBehavior.Strict);` In case this leads to an exception that all invocations need a setup, read that exception carefully.

Comment: Is the `Car` class `: Entity<int>`, and have you enabled feature "nullable reference types" (since you write `Task<T?>` where `T` is a type parameter constrained to `Entity<>`?

Comment: Yes, Car is Entity class.  Not sure about enabling feature nullable ref. types though. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer; just a lengthy comment to report that this complete code:

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    ICarRepository CarRepository { get; }
}
public interface ICarRepository : IRepository<Car, int>
{
}
public interface IRepository<T, TId> where T : Entity<TId>
{
    Task<T?> GetById(TId id);                                  // question mark on T? is allowed; T is a reference type; nullable reference types are enabled
}
public class Car : Entity<int>
{
    internal string? Name { get; init; }
}
public class Entity<T>
{
}

public class F
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();          // also works: new Mock<IUnitOfWork>(MockBehavior.Strict)

        unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.CarRepository.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new Car { Name = "test", });

        Car? car2 = await unitOfWorkMock.Object.CarRepository.GetById(1);

        // car2 is nonnull and instance has 'Name' equal to "test"
    }
}
```

together with Moq version 4.18.4, does *not* reproduce the problem. `car2` is as expected at the bottom of `Test()`.

So the asker must supply more details in the question. Try to prepare a complete reproduction code (with no types implicit).